# best way to select followers posts using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have these tables in database

Users table

```
UserId | Username | password
```

Users Posts Table

```
PostId | PostsTitle | PostUser (The id of the User who post this )
```

Following Table

```
FollowId | Following | Follower
```

Now what is the best way to get the people i follow posts order by id in desc way

like twitter do

i came up with this MySql code i don't know if it's the best way to do this or there is another way to

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE PostUser in (
    SELECT follower 
    from Following 
    where Following=$loggedin_user);
```

i found this answer in here ([Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47268/query-to-get-reposts-from-people-the-user-is-following))

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it, which I would recommend and instead of using IN()

```
SELECT
      Posts.PostId
    , Posts.PostsTitle
    , Posts.PostUser
FROM Posts
      INNER JOIN Following
                  ON Posts.PostUser = Following.Follower
WHERE Following.Following = $loggedin_user
;
```